# Sepia overtone filter in BMP

Tags: c, colors, bitmap, bmp

Before I dedicate a whole lot of time in finding out the answer of this question, it might be someone.. that has a clue already.

In my Graphic Library, I just created sepia effect, based on luminosity.
But this is just a picture with subtracted colors with the the Sepia color remaining. I know that there are 3 kinds of Sepia.

- Sepia Lum (What I have)
- Sepia Hot (What I also have)
- Sepia Overtone (What I am trying to have)

That 3rd kind of Sepia (Sepia Overtone) is some sort of a filter that as I see decreases the saturation and adds a specific amount of yellow to all the pixels. "Snapchat" the app for Android has it:
[image]
[image]

---

My question is.. what am I supposed to do with the pixels? How do I apply this filter? Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a regular Sepia, evenly reduce its luminosity by around 0.75, and adjust the weights of the RGB channels to match the weights of the original image. 
This is what I get by doing that:
[image]

And this is the Blurate description of the filter:
[image]

Comment: It looks close enough, good work! Although this is some sort of vintage filter (i.e "hot" is adjusted as well).